# how long can i store data in cPickle?

Tags: python, pickle

I'm storing a list of dictionaries in cPickle, but need to be able to add and remove to/from it occasionally. If I store the dictionary data in `cPickle`, is there some sort of limit on when I will be able to load it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store it for as long as you want. It's just a file. However, if your data structures start becoming complicated, it can become tedious and time consuming to unpickle, update and pickle the data again. Also, it's just file access so you have to handle concurrency issues by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No. cPickle just writes data to files and reads it back; why would you think there would be a limit?

Answer (score 0):

cPickle is just a faster implementation of pickle. You can use it to convert a python object to its string equivalent and retrieve it back by unpickling.

You can do one of the two things with a pickled object:

1. Do not write to a file

   In this case, the scope of your pickled data is similar to that of
   any other variable.
2. Write to a file

   We can write this pickled data to a file and read it whenever we
   want and get back the python objects/data structures. Your pickled
   data is safe as long as your pickled file is stored on the disk.